# iMacros saveas not saving any data

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros, data-extraction

I have a simple script and a big problem I do not know how to deal with.

```
iimPlay("CODE: TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:ImageContainer EXTRACT=HTM");
iimPlay("CODE: SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=+*");
```

The tag output is ok (checked via alert(iimGetLastExtract())) and extracts the html code of the ImageContainer div.
However, the saveas saves... nothing... just [BOM]""[BOM]

Am I missing some command ?
I am using FF 37.0.2 and iMacros 8.9.2 for FF.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the !EXTRACT parameter gets reset between iimPlay commands, to prevent this, Ive used simple 1-string macro that fixed the problem:

```
macro = "CODE:\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:ImageContainer EXTRACT=HTM\n";
macro += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=+*";
iimPlay(macro);
```